# Prove area using simple sums and given sum

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation, area

I am supposed to prove that the given sum `P` has area `h^3/3,` I think I can do this by using the induction axiom but I'm pretty lost as to how I even begin to tackle this problem. It was suggested to use approximations with simple sums, I have no clue on what those would be. So first of, how do I think to come up those simple sums?

P
   
  =
   
  {
  (
  x
  ,
   
  y
  )
   
  ∈
   
  
    ℝ
    
      ^2
       
    
  
  |
   
  0
   
  ≤
   
  y
   
  <
   
  
    x
    ^2
  
   
  a
  n
  d
   
  0
   
  ≤
   
  x
   
  <
   
  h
  }

Answer (score 1):

Since the area under a curve $$y=x^2, 0\le x\le h$$ is the definite integral $$\int _0^h x^2 dx = \frac {h^3}{3}$$

You are asked to write a Riemann's Sum for that integral and find the  limit  to get the answer.

A review of the definition of definite integral as a limit of the Riemann's Sum would be very helpful.